# How to move horizontal scroll giving size to left or right?

Tags: android

How to move horizontal scroll by giving size to left or right using programmable way?
Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking. Are you looking to add a horizontal scroll bar to a layout object?

Comment: yep. I am trying to move Layout in Horizontal scroll view. Tried scrollTo(). but no luck

Comment: @Ferdinand Are you wanting to scroll left and right?

Comment: I hope this link will be help full to you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656949/how-to-implement-horizontalscrollview-like-gallery

Answer (score 0):

Check out [smoothScrollBy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html#smoothScrollBy(int,%20int))

```
hScrollView.smoothScrollBy(5, 0);
```