# How to implement HorizontalScrollView like Gallery?

Tags: android, android-gallery, horizontalscrollview

I want to implement `Horizontal ScrollView` with some features of Gallery,
[image]

In Gallery the scroll made at some distance it arrange in pair, i.e If we have three images shown in screen, clicking last image will arrange at center.

How would I implement `HorizontalSCrollView` as mentioned?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18075811/726863

Comment: Can you help me on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33219942/horitzontalscrollview-or-carrousel)? :D

Comment: @Skizo: didn't find the solution from 2nd answer you get for that question ?

Comment: Yeye now I got the solution

Comment: good ... :D, can you share with me link or code for that solution ?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Try this code:

*activity_main.xml*

> ```
> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
> android:layout_width="fill_parent"
> android:layout_height="100dip"
> tools:context=".MainActivity" >
> <HorizontalScrollView
>     android:id="@+id/hsv"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>     android:fillViewport="true"
>     android:measureAllChildren="false"
>     android:scrollbars="none" >
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:id="@+id/innerLay"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:gravity="center_vertical"
>         android:orientation="horizontal" >
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:id="@+id/asthma_action_plan"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:gravity="center"
>             android:orientation="vertical" >
>             <RelativeLayout
>                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="match_parent" >
>                 <ImageView
>                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                     android:src="@drawable/action_plan" />
>                 <TextView
>                     android:layout_width="0.2dp"
>                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>                     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>                     android:background="@drawable/ln" />
>             </RelativeLayout>
>         </LinearLayout>
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:id="@+id/controlled_medication"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:gravity="center"
>             android:orientation="vertical" >
>             <RelativeLayout
>                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="match_parent" >
>                 <ImageView
>                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                     android:src="@drawable/controlled" />
>                 <TextView
>                     android:layout_width="0.2dp"
>                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>                     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>                     android:background="@drawable/ln" />
>             </RelativeLayout>
>         </LinearLayout>
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:id="@+id/as_needed_medication"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:gravity="center"
>             android:orientation="vertical" >
>             <RelativeLayout
>                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
>                 android:orientation="horizontal" >
>                 <ImageView
>                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                     android:src="@drawable/as_needed" />
>                 <TextView
>                     android:layout_width="0.2dp"
>                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>                     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>                     android:background="@drawable/ln" />
>             </RelativeLayout>
>         </LinearLayout>
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:id="@+id/rescue_medication"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:gravity="center"
>             android:orientation="vertical" >
>             <RelativeLayout
>                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="match_parent" >
>                 <ImageView
>                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                     android:src="@drawable/rescue" />
>                 <TextView
>                     android:layout_width="0.2dp"
>                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>                     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>                     android:background="@drawable/ln" />
>             </RelativeLayout>
>         </LinearLayout>
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:id="@+id/your_symptoms"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:gravity="center"
>             android:orientation="vertical" >
>             <RelativeLayout
>                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="match_parent" >
>                 <ImageView
>                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                     android:src="@drawable/symptoms" />
>                 <TextView
>                     android:layout_width="0.2dp"
>                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>                     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>                     android:background="@drawable/ln" />
>             </RelativeLayout>
>         </LinearLayout>
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:id="@+id/your_triggers"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:gravity="center"
>             android:orientation="vertical" >
>             <RelativeLayout
>                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="match_parent" >
>                 <ImageView
>                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                     android:src="@drawable/triggers" />
>                 <TextView
>                     android:layout_width="0.2dp"
>                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>                     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>                     android:background="@drawable/ln" />
>             </RelativeLayout>
>         </LinearLayout>
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:id="@+id/wheeze_rate"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:gravity="center"
>             android:orientation="vertical" >
>             <RelativeLayout
>                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="match_parent" >
>                 <ImageView
>                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                     android:src="@drawable/wheeze_rate" />
>                 <TextView
>                     android:layout_width="0.2dp"
>                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>                     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>                     android:background="@drawable/ln" />
>             </RelativeLayout>
>         </LinearLayout>
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:id="@+id/peak_flow"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:gravity="center"
>             android:orientation="vertical" >
>             <RelativeLayout
>                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="match_parent" >
>                 <ImageView
>                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                     android:src="@drawable/peak_flow" />
>                 <TextView
>                     android:layout_width="0.2dp"
>                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>                     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>                     android:background="@drawable/ln" />
>             </RelativeLayout>
>         </LinearLayout>
>     </LinearLayout>
> </HorizontalScrollView>
> <TextView
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="0.2dp"
>     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/hsv"
>     android:background="@drawable/ln" />
> <LinearLayout
>     android:id="@+id/prev"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>     android:paddingLeft="5dip"
>     android:paddingRight="5dip"
>     android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >
>     <ImageView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
>         android:src="@drawable/prev_arrow" />
> </LinearLayout>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:id="@+id/next"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>     android:paddingLeft="5dip"
>     android:paddingRight="5dip"
>     android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >
>     <ImageView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
>         android:src="@drawable/next_arrow" />
> </LinearLayout>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

*grid_item.xml*

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="match_parent"
> android:orientation="vertical" >
> <ImageView
>     android:id="@+id/imageView1"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="100dp"
>     android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

*MainActivity.java*

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

LinearLayout asthmaActionPlan, controlledMedication, asNeededMedication,
        rescueMedication, yourSymtoms, yourTriggers, wheezeRate, peakFlow;
LayoutParams params;
LinearLayout next, prev;
int viewWidth;
GestureDetector gestureDetector = null;
HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView;
ArrayList<LinearLayout> layouts;
int parentLeft, parentRight;
int mWidth;
int currPosition, prevPosition;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    prev = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.prev);
    next = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.next);
    horizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.hsv);
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
    asthmaActionPlan = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.asthma_action_plan);
    controlledMedication = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.controlled_medication);
    asNeededMedication = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.as_needed_medication);
    rescueMedication = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rescue_medication);
    yourSymtoms = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_symptoms);
    yourTriggers = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_triggers);
    wheezeRate = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.wheeze_rate);
    peakFlow = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.peak_flow);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    mWidth = display.getWidth(); // deprecated
    viewWidth = mWidth / 3;
    layouts = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();
    params = new LayoutParams(viewWidth, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    asthmaActionPlan.setLayoutParams(params);
    controlledMedication.setLayoutParams(params);
    asNeededMedication.setLayoutParams(params);
    rescueMedication.setLayoutParams(params);
    yourSymtoms.setLayoutParams(params);
    yourTriggers.setLayoutParams(params);
    wheezeRate.setLayoutParams(params);
    peakFlow.setLayoutParams(params);

    layouts.add(asthmaActionPlan);
    layouts.add(controlledMedication);
    layouts.add(asNeededMedication);
    layouts.add(rescueMedication);
    layouts.add(yourSymtoms);
    layouts.add(yourTriggers);
    layouts.add(wheezeRate);
    layouts.add(peakFlow);

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    horizontalScrollView.smoothScrollTo(
                            (int) horizontalScrollView.getScrollX()
                                    + viewWidth,
                            (int) horizontalScrollView.getScrollY());
                }
            }, 100L);
        }
    });

    prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    horizontalScrollView.smoothScrollTo(
                            (int) horizontalScrollView.getScrollX()
                                    - viewWidth,
                            (int) horizontalScrollView.getScrollY());
                }
            }, 100L);
        }
    });

    horizontalScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        if (e1.getX() < e2.getX()) {
            currPosition = getVisibleViews("left");
        } else {
            currPosition = getVisibleViews("right");
        }

        horizontalScrollView.smoothScrollTo(layouts.get(currPosition)
                .getLeft(), 0);
        return true;
    }
}

public int getVisibleViews(String direction) {
    Rect hitRect = new Rect();
    int position = 0;
    int rightCounter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < layouts.size(); i++) {
        if (layouts.get(i).getLocalVisibleRect(hitRect)) {
            if (direction.equals("left")) {
                position = i;
                break;
            } else if (direction.equals("right")) {
                rightCounter++;
                position = i;
                if (rightCounter == 2)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return position;
}
}
```

Let me know if any issue
enjoy...

Comment: yes, you will have to create custom HorizontalScroll view to add this feature.

Comment: That's a good example. But a little explanations would make it much better

Comment: Oh my... please don't implement your layout like this. There's about 5 layers of nested view hell here.

Comment: This answer just throws some code at you, rather than making a minimal example that is easily understandable

Answer (score 32):

Here is my layout:

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding" >

       <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/shapeLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

And I populate it in the code with dynamic check-boxes.

Answer (score 4):

You may use HorizontalScrollView to implement Horizontal scrolling.

Code

```
<HorizontalScrollView
android:id="@+id/hsv"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
 android:layout_weight="0"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:measureAllChildren="false"
android:scrollbars="none" >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/innerLay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

featured.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="160dp"
   android:layout_margin="4dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

      <RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
>

<ProgressBar                
    android:layout_width="15dip"       
    android:layout_height="15dip"
    android:id="@+id/progress" 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"       
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"       
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#20000000"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:text="Image Text" />

      </RelativeLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater;

    inflater=getLayoutInflater();
    LinearLayout inLay=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.innerLay);

    for(int x=0;x<10;x++)
    {
        inLay.addView(getView(x));
    }




 View getView(final int x)
{
   View rootView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.featured_item,null);

   ImageView image = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);

   //Thease Two Line is sufficient my dear to implement lazyLoading
   AQuery aq = new AQuery(rootView);
   String url="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5035/5802797131_a729dac808_s.jpg";
   aq.id(image).progress(R.id.progress).image(url, true, true, 0, R.drawable.placeholder1);
   image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
     Toast.makeText(PhotoActivity.this, "Click Here Postion "+x,     

         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
   return rootView;
       }
```

Note: to implement lazy loading, please use this link for AQUERY

https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/07/implement-gallery-like.html) is a good tutorial with code. Let me know if it works for you! [This](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/05/image-switcher-view-android-developer.html) is also a good tutorial.

**EDIT**

In [This](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/05/image-switcher-view-android-developer.html) example, all you need to do is add this line:

```
gallery.setSelection(1);
```

after setting the adapter to gallery object, that is this line:

```
gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

**UPDATE1**

Alright, I got your problem. This [open source library](https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android) is your solution. I also have used it for one of my projects. Hope this will solve your problem finally.

**UPDATE2:**

I would suggest you to go through this [tutorial](http://iotasol.blogspot.in/2011/08/creating-custom-horizontal-scroll-view.html). You might get idea. I think I got your problem, you want the **horizontal scrollview with snap**. Try to search with that keyword on google or out here, you might get your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something similar with [Horizontal Variable ListView](https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView) 
The only drawback is, it works only with Android 2.3 and later.

Using this library is as simple as implementing a ListView with a corresponding Adapter. The library also provides an [example](https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView/tree/master/Demo)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a horizontal **ListView** in every row of **ListView** if you want single 
You can do the following

Here I am just creating **horizontalListView** of Thumbnail of Videos 
Like this

[image]

The idea is  just continuously add the **ImageView** to the child of LinearLayout in **HorizontalscrollView**

**Note:** remember to fire **.removeAllViews();** before next time load other wise it will add duplicate child

```
Cursor mImageCursor = db.getPlaylistVideoImage(playlistId);
mVideosThumbs.removeAllViews();
if (mImageCursor != null && mImageCursor.getCount() > 0) {
    for (int index = 0; index < mImageCursor.getCount(); index++) {
        mImageCursor.moveToPosition(index);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) imageViewInfalter.inflate(
            R.layout.image_view, null);
                    name = mImageCursor.getString(mImageCursor
                    .getColumnIndex("LogoDefaultName"));
        logoFile = new File(MyApplication.LOCAL_LOGO_PATH, name);
                    if (logoFile.exists()) {    
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(logoFile);
                iv.setImageURI(uri);                    
            }
            iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            mVideosThumbs.addView(iv);
    }
    mImageCursor.close();
    mImageCursor = null;
    } else {
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) imageViewInfalter.inflate(
                    R.layout.image_view, null);
        String name = "";
        File logoFile;
        name = mImageCursor.getString(mImageCursor
                    .getColumnIndex("LogoMediumName"));
        logoFile = new File(MyApplication.LOCAL_LOGO_PATH, name);
        if (logoFile.exists()) {
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(logoFile);
            iv.setImageURI(uri);
            }
        }
```

My xml for HorizontalListView

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutTitle"
    android:background="@drawable/shelf"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/Playlist_TopBottom_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/playlist_RightLeft_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/playlist_RightLeft_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/Playlist_TopBottom_margin" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutVideos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

and Also my Image View as each child

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


  android:id="@+id/imageViewThumb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/action_settings"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:maxHeight="200dp"
    android:maxWidth="240dp"
    android:padding="@dimen/playlist_image_padding"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/loading" />
```

To learn More you can follow the following links which have some easy samples

1. http://www.dev-smart.com/?p=34
2. [Horizontal ListView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240331/horizontal-listview-in-android)