# How to prevent imageview overlapping in android

Tags: android, xml, imageview, android-relativelayout

i wanna put multiple imageview in a row like this

http://imgur.com/wYpAgxE

but there is some bugs, the imageview are overlap on top of each other, i want to place them side by side with each other

http://imgur.com/WUHbzCd

Below is my XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" > 

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="182dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/music_720p" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="182dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="70dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/video_720p" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="182dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="70dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/photo_720p" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="182dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/web_720p" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="182dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/setting_720p" /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `GridView` or `HorzontalScrollView`. And use `RelativeLayout` property properly.

Comment: Do You know about `GridView` & HorizontalScrollView` in android?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you should go for `HorizontalScrollView` which provides functionality as you want.

Checkout link shows you how you can implement [HorizontolScrollView](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/07/implement-gallery-like.html)

I hope this will help you.

You can also check the answer of vijju who have shown implementation totally [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19448610/1839336)

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" > 

  <HorizontalScrollView
      android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
      android:scrollbars="none" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/setupImageView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/uploadImageView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/visulizationImageView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/setupImageView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/uploadImageView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/visulizationImageView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please try this. I hope help you.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have used **wrap_content** everywhere,so u can either reduce the width and height of your images or you can define it explicitly in layout file or .java file.

For your scenario using **GridLayout** is better option than using **RelativeLayout**.try it...
Here is a good example on GridLayout :- http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_the_Android_GridLayout_in_XML_Layout_Resources

Comment: I change to GridLayout and it works perfectly, thanks!