# How can I Create the view as shown in the Image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-tabs

I need to create a view as shown in the image attached, How can I achieve the same, or if there is any view or library for the same can anyone would tell me its name.
[image]

**Note:**Its a Calander which can be scrolled right and left. which looks like a tab. On clicking on each Date it shows an Activity/Fragment with that date's appointment details.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: add scroll view in Horizontal view...

Comment: @Destro so should I put a calander in a horizontal view and add a scroll to it. But on clicking on each date it shows an Activity/Fragment with its date appointment details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656949/how-to-implement-horizontalscrollview-like-gallery You Should Take a look here

Comment: You can use TabLayout with custom view.

Comment: ya add calendar in horizontal view and add a fragment in below the scroll layout and  when click the day the show the view in fragment..

Comment: @PravinsinghWaghela you can see if any of this libraries works for you https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui/blob/master/pages/Calendar.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways in which you can accomplish this:

1. Create a custom view for the calendar item (i.e, the blue square box in the picture). Then have a layout like below and dynamically add all your calendar items (custom view) as child to the `LinearLayout`. On click of a child, you could show the `Fragment` below the horizontal scroll view. More info on this here: [How to implement HorizontalScrollView like Gallery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656949/how-to-implement-horizontalscrollview-like-gallery)

   ```
   <HorizontalScrollView>
        <LinearLayout>
              <!-- Add your custom view as children to this layout -->
        </LinearLayout>
   </HorizontalScrollView>
   ```
2. You need to create a horizontal `ListView`. You can now get this done using `RecyclerView`. Here you need to create a layout of the calendar item and then inflate this in the `RecylerView` for each row (column here). OnItemClick you can show the `Fragment` below the `RecyclerView`. More info here: [How to build a Horizontal ListView with RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460300/how-to-build-a-horizontal-listview-with-recyclerview)