# How to achieve a similar horizontal scrolling widget like a custom seekbar?

Tags: android, user-interface, widget, components

What is the name of this android widget?
It is like a seekbar and it allows you to choose values be horizontal scrolling?
Is it fully custom? If yes, can you point me on the right direction on how I can achieve something similar?

[Android widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m8dD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HorizontalScrollView widget is something you can use (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)

You can customize the look and feel of the same. Here is something to help you get started.

[How to implement HorizontalScrollView like Gallery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656949/how-to-implement-horizontalscrollview-like-gallery)

Hope this helps!