# horizontalscrollview with image and text is possible to add two views

Tags: android, view, horizontalscrollview

I want to add two child views to a horizontal scroll view. The two views are a `ImageView` and a `TextView` and the `TextView` should be below the `ImageView, both the view should scroll horizontally  Is it possible to achieve this? How can it be added? I am new to android.

Thanks in advance.

in my fragment:

```
LinearLayout lv = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.textl);
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(getContext());
            TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
            tv.setText(text[i]);   //defined text and images
            iv.setImageResource(images[i]);
            lv.addView(iv);
            lv.addView(tv);
```

xml:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/hs">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/bottle"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/textl"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use **LinearLayout with vertical orientation** inside horizontal scroll view then use image and text view inside LinearLayout.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/hsv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/to" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/subject" />


</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Ok I'll try Thank you for your response

Comment: when I am adding image and text I got error has The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: Will you please share your java file.

Answer (score 1):

The best possible way is to use RecyclerView. This is best way to use it as it scale itself and also elements can be loaded on the fly.
if you are in **activity** then in **onCreate** method

```
// recyclerView is id mentioned in xml file
 RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

** your adapter init goes here **
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(**adapter object**);
```

for details post your code - will help you. For Fragments you need to do same with slight changes

Note: you should also define your recyclerview in your xml file

Answer (score 0):

All three questions answers :

> **Textview below Imageview as shown below,**
>
> **Yes, it is possible**
>
> **Yo can check below xml code**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dip">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hsv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:measureAllChildren="false"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/innerLay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iV1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/next_"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/iV1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="hello"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think if we add like this I think it get error - The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first when adding text and image to those one

Comment: No, it will not throw error , please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656949/how-to-implement-horizontalscrollview-like-gallery

Comment: yeah I am adding image and text to the both imageview and textview dynamically but it getting issue The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526874/call-removeview-on-the-childs-parent-first and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28071349/the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent-you-must-call-removeview-on-the-chil

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="Hello" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="Hello"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```