# ScrollView - How to enable horizontal scrolling in ScrollView

Tags: java, android, textview, scrollview

So I have a `ScrollView` which has a `TextView` inside. When the `String` for the text is longer than the screen width, It simply shifting in the next line. I want to avoid the new lining by adding `HorizontalScrolling` in `ScrollView`. Also, I want to make the text selectable so the user can copy the text. Is it possible?

```
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:textIsSelectable="true"
                    android:justificationMode="inter_word"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    tools:targetApi="o" />
        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: [this may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656949/how-to-implement-horizontalscrollview-like-gallery)

Comment: The ScrollView Should be both Horizontal and Vertical.

Comment: there is an attribute called `orientation` set it  to `horizontal` will you confirm whether or not it works for you

Comment: @hiwajalal Thanks, I figured it out. It was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <HorizontalScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:background="#000000"/>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView 
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="Horizontal scroll text view"/>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: The ScrollView Should be both Horizontal and Vertical.