# Scroll within multiple TextViews at once - Android

Tags: java, android, scroll, textview

I have three TextViews sitting side by side in a ListView. I would like to be able to scroll horizontally the text in one TextView and have the other two simultaneously scroll. Is there a straightforward way to do this? I haven't found anything helpful in the documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement HorizontalScrollView like Gallery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656949/how-to-implement-horizontalscrollview-like-gallery)

Answer (score 1):

Drop the listView, and use this tag `<HorizontalScrollView` instead.

inside of it make a `LinearLayout` and make it `android:orientation="horizontal"`.

inside of it put your `Textviews`